How to generalize a value of a specific year to every row of a group?
I have a large dataset containing values for each year for different countries. I want to create an additionnal column containing the value for that country in the latest year.
I have tried filtering the dataset by the latest years through ifelse loops (nearly everything has either 2023 or 2022) and then remerging it with the main dataset, but it gives me many duplicates which I don't understand why. Any ideas on a how to not rely on filter/merge methods?
With this mock data:
countries <- c('A','A','A','B','B','C')
years <- c('2000','2001','2002','1999','2001','2000')
values <- c(1,3,1,2,3,2)
df <- data.frame(countries,years,values)



ID
Year
Value




A
2000
1


A
2001
3


A
2002
1


B
1999
2


B
2001
3


C
2001
2



I want to obtain the following result, with an additionnal Latest Value in df:



ID
Year
Value
Latest_Value




A
2000
1
1


A
2001
3
1


A
2002
1
1


B
1999
2
3


B
2001
3
3


C
2001
2
2




Base R
Use ave to get the last value by country.
with(df, ave(values, countries, FUN = \(x) x[length(x)]))
#> [1] 1 1 1 3 3 2

Created on 2024-10-10 with reprex v2.1.1
Then assign this return vector to a new column.
df$Latest_Value <- with(df, ave(values, countries, FUN = \(x) x[length(x)]))


Package dplyr
Use last after grouping by countries.
In the code below, arrange makes sure the data is sorted by country and year
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

countries <- c('A','A','A','B','B','C')
years <- c('2000','2001','2002','1999','2001','2000')
values <- c(1,3,1,2,3,2)
df <- data.frame(countries,years,values)

df %>%
  arrange(countries, years) %>%
  mutate(Latest_Value = last(values), .by = countries)
#>   countries years values Latest_Value
#> 1         A  2000      1            1
#> 2         A  2001      3            1
#> 3         A  2002      1            1
#> 4         B  1999      2            3
#> 5         B  2001      3            3
#> 6         C  2000      2            2

Created on 2024-10-10 with reprex v2.1.1

The example with ave is great, and very simple. I'd just throw in some sorting beforehand, to make sure x[length(x)] gets the latest year, which might not be the last row.

Thanks for all the excellent solutions, the one with arrange worked perfectly!

Using only base functions:
Split the data.frame by country, use which.max to get the latest value for each country, and then assign them to a new column in the original data.frame by matching the years with the new vector:
latests <- sapply(split(df, df$countries), \(x) x$value[which.max(x$years)])
df$Latest_Value <- latests[match(df$countries, names(latests))]

> df
  countries years values Latest_Value
1         A  2000      1            1
2         A  2001      3            1
3         A  2002      1            1
4         B  1999      2            3
5         B  2001      3            3
6         C  2000      2            2


You can try
> library(dplyr)

> df %>% mutate(latest_Value = values[which.max(years)], .by = countries)
  countries years values latest_Value
1         A  2000      1            1
2         A  2001      3            1
3         A  2002      1            1
4         B  1999      2            3
5         B  2001      3            3
6         C  2000      2            2

